# Navigator.push will be called again when focusing on textfield on the destination page after Navigator.push

Tags: flutter

The following phenomenon occurs.

1. Transition from `FirstPage` to `NextPage` by `Navigation.push`.
2. Select a `TextField` of the `NextPage`.
3. 1 is called again.
4. Done with the keyboard.
5. 1 is called again.

Below is the source.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FirstPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("sample"),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              print("Before call NextPage()");
              return NextPage();
            }),
          );
        },
        child: Text("next page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("next page"),
      ),
      body: TextField(),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is animated gif where the log is printed when taping TextField and DONE keyboard.

[image]

Why does this happen? (bug?)
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, even though that log is called multiple times, you are only seeing a transition on the first one, or, in another words, you’re getting the desired effect. This happens for a reason. Let’s break it down:

With Flutter, `builders` can be called multiple times, for multiple reasons and should be idempotent (not affect logic business);

That being said, when you’re navigating to your second screen, you’re building a `TextFormField` that is a child of a *Stateless Widget*`, which should be immutable. That means that its final values (if needed) should be passed in the constructor and each time a state changes (like the default text of the field, for example) will then require changes and thus rebuild the view by triggering the builder;

So, if you, for example, use a *Stateful Widget* instead, then, your builder won’t probably be called and only the `build` method of its *State*.

You can find a discussion about this in a similar closed issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14124)

Comment: thank you very much.I know that the builder method should be idempotent, but WidgetBuilder does not know the same reason.
Can you explain why? 
And changing to StatefulWidget was the same result.

Comment: That's because you are changing the state of the `TextFormField`. Anyway, that's a normal behavior and you shouldn't be worried, since the builder will be called when needs to rebuild its child.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved by:

1. create a global variable, say gstrCurPage = 'First'
2. In your main widget, do not return firstpage() only, instead, add a 'switch' statement, return firstpage() or nextpage() according to gstrCurPage.
3. Inside the button click of the first page, set gstrCurPage = 'Next'

To allow your 'Many Pages' to be stored inside 'Many Dart Files', first of all, create a dart file called 'GlobalVariables.dart' and stores all 'Global Variables' inside this file.

```
class gv {
    // Declare Global Variables Here to be accessed by all 'Pages'
    // These variables must be static !!!
    static String gstrCurPage = 'First';
}
```

The following is the update of your original program:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'GlobalVariables.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (gv.gstrCurPage) {
        case 'First':
            return MaterialApp(
                home: FirstPage(),
            );
            break;
        case 'Next':
            return MaterialApp(
                home: NextPage(),
            );
            break;
        default:
            return MaterialApp(
                home: FirstPage(),
            );
    }
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("sample"),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              print("Before call NextPage()");
              gv.gstrCurPage = 'Next';
              return NextPage();
            }),
          );
        },
        child: Text("next page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("next page"),
      ),
      body: TextField(),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, you can put your 'First Page' and 'Next Page' (as well as other pages) in separate dart files, all of them should import 'GlobalVariables.dart'.  Any changes in the variables defined in class gv, will be 'known' by all pages.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't quite understand. Could you write code that can be solved?

Comment: Pls. check the modified answer